# How to not get a fraud detection error at outlook

Tags: outlook, phpmailer, html-email, email-spam, fraud-prevention

I am currently making a html email for a big client.
Visitors can enter their email in a Facebook app, and then they get a mail with instructions.
In all mail clients I've checked I pass the spam protection because I've got a valid FROM and headers, I even set up SPF records.

But at outlook.com my mail doesn't get in the spam folder, but it does add a banner with:

> Be careful. This sender is not approved by our controls for fraud detection.

I am using [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send my emails.

Is there anyway I don't get this error?

Comment: Try this tool, it will show you what is wrong with your mail http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I found a working SPF record for outlook.com.

```
v=spf1 ip4:<server IP address> include:outlook.com ~all
```

This fixed all of my problems